# Run-time 1004 error when coming from the copy sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The code below copies data from one sheet to the "LogDetails" sheet. This normally works no problem except when I go to the "LogDetails" sheet and then leave it. I get a

> Runtime 1004 error

suggesting the sheet might be protected even though I unprotect the worksheet. When I check for it in the immediate window, the sheet is unprotected. What could the issue be if the worksheet is not protected?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
    Sheets("LogDetails").Unprotect
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Address(0, 0)** Error hits here
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Environ("username")
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Now



 Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:D").AutoFit
 Application.EnableEvents = True


 End If
 End Sub
```

Recommended edits:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim shL As Worksheet

Set shL = Sheets("LogDetails")

If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
    shL.Unprotect
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    shL.Range("A" & shL.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Address(0, 0) **error hits here still
    shL.Range("A" & shL.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value
    shL.Range("A" & shL.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Environ("username")
    shL.Range("A" & shL.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Now


 shL.Columns("A:D").AutoFit
 Application.EnableEvents = True


 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure the "LogDetails" sheet is actually called that? (Check for spaces at the beginning or the end)

Comment: `Rows.Count` refers to the active sheet. If there you do not have data on column A:A, it may be a problem. Anyhow, I would suggest to  firstly declare and define the sheet in discussion: `Dim shL as Worsheet`. `Then Set shL = Sheets("LogDetails")` and use it like this: `shL.Range("A" & shL.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Address(0, 0)`. Maybe, it will help. Anyhow, it is recommended to proceed in this way, I think...

Comment: @FaneDuru so saying Sheets("LogDetails").Range... first doesn't specify the row.count to be on that worksheet?

Comment: I updated the code declare the worksheet and I'm still getting the same error. I will edit the code above.

Comment: At which line this error appear?